# connection refused ssh and dns

Tags: centos, ssh, iptables, dns, nslookup

I cannot to `ssh` or `nslookup` to this machine `vm1` that has the ip `192.168.56.2` from `ferrari` which has the ip `172.45.20.3`. I do not know why, but I am able to ssh to the `192.168.56.2` from my host machine. Iptables is disabled for testing purposes on `192.168.56.2` and `172.45.20.3`. I can also perform reverse lookups for `172.45.20.3` from `vm1`, but I cannot do forward lookups using a hostname.

```
[root@ferrari ~]# nslookup vm1 192.168.56.2
;; connection timed out; trying next origin
;; connection timed out; trying next origin
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
ssh: connect to host 192.168.56.2 port 22: Connection refused
```

vm1

```
[root@vm1 ~]# nslookup ferrari 172.45.20.3
Server:     172.45.20.3
Address:    172.45.20.3#53

Name:   ferrari.luxury.auto.ops
Address: 172.45.20.3

[root@vm1 ~]# nslookup 172.45.20.3
Server:     192.168.56.2
Address:    192.168.56.2#53

Non-authoritative answer:
3.20.45.172.in-addr.arpa    name = ferrari.luxury.auto.ops.

Authoritative answers can be found from:
20.45.172.in-addr.arpa  nameserver = ferrari.luxury.auto.ops.
ferrari.luxury.auto.ops internet address = 172.45.20.3

[root@vm1 ~]# host 172.45.20.3
3.20.45.172.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer ferrari.luxury.auto.ops.
```

Comment: is ip forwarding active on the server doing routing?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Yes, both networks allow traffic through the forward chain.

Comment: Which machine has which address? Which one can't you ssh to? From where? You've a name "vm1". How does that fit in to the situation - is it Ferrari by another name? If you have virtualisation please tell us, and include how you have set up the host and guest networks.

Comment: Is your DNS server listening to all interfaces? If it's a VM, is the virtualization host performing NAT on the VM interface?

Comment: @ErikF, I apologize for the late reply, can I go to `named.conf`and set `listen-on { any;}`. To do NAT, can I also do this rule `iptables -t nat -A postroughting -o eth0 -j masquerade`?

Comment: @roaima, sorry for late reply, vm1 has the ip of `192.168.56.2` and ferrari has the ip of `172.45.20.3`. I am trying to ssh from ferrari to vm1 or perform nslookup, and I cannot. I am using Vmware Workstation 12. I have one host machine and 2 virtual machines on different networks. one on `172.45.20.0/24` and one on `192.168.56.0/24`.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro, hello sorry for the late reply. But would the issue be resolved, by the previous comment to @ErikF?

Comment: Please check your _can_ and _cannot_ in the question body and title. You seem to be saying you cannot ssh, but then you say you can. Which is correct and what is the true problem?

Comment: @roaima sorry, I've edited the post and I hope you can better understand the problem.

Comment: So is the problem that you can ssh from your host but should not be able to do so, or that you cannot ssh from ferrari but should be able to do so? You haven't actually written a question (ending with "?") yet.